# does vim read the whole file into memory

Tags: performance, memory, vim, slowdown

When I open a file, does vim read it all into memory? I experienced significant slowdowns when I open large files. Or is it busy computing something (e.g., line number)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Vim loads the whole file into memory.

If you run `htop` in another pane you can watch it happen in real time.

If you don't have enough memory available, it will start hitting the swap which makes it take even longer.

You can disable plugins and heavy features (like syntax highlighting) to get improved performance (the `-u` effectively tells vim not to load your `~/.vimrc`):

`vim -u NONE mysqldump.sql`

However, unless you really need to *edit* the file, I prefer to just use a different tool.  I typically use `less`.  I mostly search the files in vim with `/` and `less` supports that just fine.

`less mysqldump.sql`

Comment: Vim does not load the whole file into memory. As of vim 8.2 / nvim 0.6.1, this is not true. While they map the whole file (as seen via `pmap <PID>`), they do not physically load it into memory unless used. And if used, vim only maps relevant segments of the file. See via `valgrind --tool=massif vim ...` and `ms_print`. So vim does not use up physical memory unless needed, and does not do it on it's own after opening large file. (However, certain plugins and features might attempt to index the file or otherwise process it, causing slowdown)

Answer (score 2):

Disabling features like syntax highlighting, cursorline, line numbers and so on will greatly reduce the load and make Vim snappier in these cases.

There's even [a plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) to handle that for you and [a Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files) for some background info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. It's useful to me. But I still want to know what I asked originally.

Comment: Yes, the file is loaded in memory.